# Why my date is not of current day but shows that of 1970?

Tags: android

My code:

```
Date p_selected = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.US)
                        .parse(String.valueOf(p_hour[0]) + ":" + String.valueOf(p_min[0]));
Log.d("ttt", "current_time = " + calender.getTime() + "user time = " + p_selected);
```

This is my log where current time is of 2015 and why the user time 1970?

```
current_time = Wed Sep 30 11:35:43 GMT+05:30 2015  
user time = Thu Jan 01 11:02:00 GMT+05:30 1970.
```

Anything I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

"HH:mm" in the SimpleDateFormat only parse the hour and minute, so those two match. If you add "YYYY-MM-DD" (might be dd instead of DD) you should get the date as well. And then you'll have to provide the extended input text too of course.

Comment: what u mean by extended input text here?date(2015/09/30)?

Comment: You currently only provide text to the parser for hour and minute, you need to provide text to parse year, month and day as well.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the help from @ganapat and @arodriguez, the final code is:

```
Calendar calender=Calendar.getInstance();
            int yy=calender.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mm=calender.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int dd=calender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            String date_str=new StringBuilder().append(yy).append("/").append(mm+1).append("/").append(dd).append(" ").toString();
```

I am getting the current date and passing it to simple formatter.

```
Date p_selected=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm",Locale.US).parse(date_str+String.valueOf(p_hour[0])+":"+String.valueOf(p_min[0]));
```

and now I am able to compare the both times.